# String concatination for dynamically adding classes in View

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

I am listing previously used shipping addresses for user to select. I`m dynamically adding classes

```
<div class="row">
    <% @shipping_addresses.each do |address| %>
      <ul class=<%= "shipping_address_#{address.id}" %> >
        <li><%= address['name'] %> </li>
        <li><%= address['street'] %> </li>
        <li><%= address['city'] %></li> 
        <li><%= address['country'] %></li> 
        <li><%= address['zip'] %></li> 
        <li><%= address['phone'] %> </li>
      </ul>
    <% end %>
</div> <!-- row -->
```

Problem is, that now I am trying to add a col-lg-3 bootstrap class to my ul`s, and it doesn`t work when I write it like this:

```
<ul class=<%= "shipping_address_#{address.id} col-lg-3" %> >
```

I get this output:

```
<ul class="shipping_address_38" col-lg-3="">
```

I also tried several different options and they don`t work.

Can anyone help?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual html you are outputting is

```
<ul class=shipping_address_38 col-lg-3>
```

And your browser is interpreting this as best it can. The quotation marks in your template never make it to the actual html because they're not actually part of the string.

You could do something like

```
<ul class="<%= "shipping_address_#{address.id} col-lg-3" %>" >
```

Although in my opinion you're now past the point where ERB gets difficult to read - you may wish to refactor this into a helper.